# WordPress Avada theme: Gap between drop-down elements and main nav

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'm using Avada version 3.2.1. Here's my site: [Link](https://thenoblelaw.com/)

The drop-down items under the main nav menu items are too far below when they pop out and are difficult to click. Try mousing over "About" and clicking an item below to see.

How can I fix this? I couldn't find the right bit of CSS to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Update this in your custom css to be 40px instead of 43px:

```
#nav ul ul {top: 40px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your css with this :) It will fix your problem.

```
#nav ul ul {
    top: 35px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Periapsis please upvote post and make it solution :)